# When I assemble an AST tree into a React component, the Cyrillic alphabet is converted to Unicode escape sequences

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Actually, any text other than Latin does this.

I want to add an attribute "attrName" with a value "киррилица" to the button:
`<button attrName="киррилица">текст</button>`

But when i do parsing, add attribute and then generation i have this:
`<button attrName="\u043A\u0438\u0440\u0440\u0438\u043B\u0438\u0446\u0430">текст</button>`

It happens like this:

```
const generator = require('@babel/generator').default;
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser');
const traverse = require('@babel/traverse').default;


const code = `
import React from 'react';

export const Component = () => {
  return (
    <button>текст</button>
  );
};
`

const ast = parse(code, { sourceType: "module", plugins: ['jsx', 'typescript'] });

traverse(ast, {
  JSXOpeningElement(path) {
    const { attributes } = path.node || {};

    const newAttr = {
      type: 'JSXAttribute',
      name: {
        type: 'JSXIdentifier',
        name: 'attrName',
      },
      value: {
        type: 'StringLiteral',
        value: 'киррилица',
      },
    }

    attributes.push(newAttr)
  },
}, { scope: {} });

const options = { retainLines: true, comments: true };
const output = generator(ast, options, code).code;

console.log('output code: ', output);
```

I assume that the conclusion will be:

```
output code:  
import React from 'react';

export const Component = () => {
  return (
    <button attrName="киррилица">текст</button>);

};
```

But in the end I have this:

```
output code:  
import React from 'react';

export const Component = () => {
  return (
    <button attrName="\u043A\u0438\u0440\u0440\u0438\u043B\u0438\u0446\u0430">текст</button>);

};
```

Is it possible to leave the original text?

Comment: *"Is it possible to leave the original text?"* In the end, it *is* the original text, just written using Unicode escape sequences instead of Cyrillic glyphs. It's the same value (though rather less readable), just like the sequence `\u0041` is the same as `A` (though rather less readable). Interesting thing for Babel to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below configurations to generator options

```
  generatorOpts: {
    jsescOption: {
      minimal: true,
    },
  },
```

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9804

I checked this solution and it worked for me.